# Image Classification Toolbar - Training Samples Manager Unselectable - ArcGIS

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, classification, landsat, toolbar

I am having an issue with this toolbar. 
I have it enabled but many options are greyed out. The training samples manager is unselectable. 
I have two raster files I just created from Landsat data that I want to create classes on by using the image classification toolbar.

(I have spatial analyst enabled and I just upgraded from ArcGIS 10.3 to 10.4.)

Here is my Table of Contents:

[image]

and the Image Classification Toolbar:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you to those who helped me improve my question. 
Silly mistake on my part. I had the Spatial Analyst toolbar enabled but not the extension.

Answer: Enable Spatial Analyst extension.